# Lighthouse shows NO_FMP error when running an audit

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I want to make my personal website a PWA. You can find it at [francoscarpa.com](https://francoscarpa.com). To make it a PWA I implemented a service worker on it. I can’t understand why, running an audit with Chrome’s Lighthouse, I get this error: ***“Something went wrong with recording the trace over your page load. Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_FMP)”***.

In particular, I get this error on the "Performance" and "Progressive Web App" tabs. Specifically, they shows under:

- First Meaningful Paint;
- First CPU Idle;
- Time to Interactive.

Moreover, Lighthouse suggests me to:

- Defer offscreen images;
- Avoid multiple page redirects;
- Ensure text remains visible during webfont load.

The fun fact is that I don’t use images on the page I run the test (the homepage, `/`). I can’t figure out what causes the NO_FMP error. Here’s an image from the audit results:

[image]

The errors happen 90% of the time I run a new audit. I guess that, if you run an audit on my website from your machine, you get the same results. If not, try to run more than one audit. I don’t understand under which circumstances I get there errors.